# Multiple Sub Query by Zend

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have one question about query in Zend with this data:

```
+--------+-----------+
| Sender | Recipient |
+--------+-----------+
|   1010 |      1011 |
|   1011 |      1012 |
|   1011 |      1010 |
|   1012 |      1011 |
|   1012 |      1000 |
+--------+-----------+
```

If I query for `1010` the answer should be `1012`, because `1010` is sender for recipient `1011` and `1011` is sender for recipient `1012`:

```
1010->1011->1012
```

If input `1011` the answer should be `1011`, `1000` and `1011`:

```
1011->1012->1011,1000    
1011->1010->1011
```

How do I query in one line for Zend framework?

Comment: Why does a query for `1010` not return `1010` in addition to `1012` (since `1011` is a sender for both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a self-join:

```
$db->select()
->from(array('a' => 'my_table'), array())
->join(array('b' => 'my_table'), 'b.Sender = a.Recipient', array('Recipient'))
->where('a.Sender = ?', $id)
```